# HTML jQuery - Simple 2 pages with JS not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have those two simple pages with jQuery functions not working, though the first page was working ok before i put the other.
  -  WAMP on Win7

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</html>
```

**jQuery js.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('page1');
});
```

**page2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>eee</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/js_page2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**js_page2.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('page2');
});
```

Comment: Did you find any error in console ?

Comment: No sir just empty page without any warning or popup blocked notification

Comment: In browser, there is a option for `Developer Tool(F12)`, find `console` tab in it..

Comment: did you control your path ?

Comment: Your `<script>` tags are not contained in the `<body>` of `index.php`

Comment: i will try clearing the browse catch , and see.  _ and  Ryon - thank you .

Comment: Check errors in your console by hitting f12. Also is `js` folder exists?

Comment: I do not believe it , i didnot cleared the browser catch . i 've waseted my entire day looking for solution ... but how can we disable browser catch datat for opera and chrome

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to link the js file to page 2, link it and everything will work as expected.

Comment: The question shows it is already added: `<script src="js/js_page2.js"></script>`

Comment: its already added ...

Comment: Ok, now no problems with the code and should work perfectly, unless the js files are not in the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your using the correct path to the javascript files, the code looks correct otherwise.

Pasting your code into a fiddle and just using the jQuery instead of the import works fine.